# Share prototype instance through requirejs without singelton pattern?

Tags: javascript, singleton, instance, requirejs, amd

I got a mediator object which handles sandboxes.

Each sandbox has to register at the mediator. Because I also use requirejs this is a little problem because I have no idea how I could share the instance and not the prototype:

**mediator.js**

```
define([], function() {
    var Mediator = function() {};
    Mediator.prototype.start = function() {};
    Mediator.prototype.stop = function() {};
    Mediator.prototype.register = function() {};
    Mediator.prototype.unregister = function() {};
    return Mediator;
});
```

**sandbox_one.js**

```
define(['mediator'], function(Mediator) {
    var mediator = new Mediator();
    mediator.register('sandboxOne', SandboxObject);
});
```

**sandbox_two.js**

```
define(['mediator'], function(Mediator) {
    var mediator = new Mediator();
    mediator.register('sandboxtwo', SandboxObject);
});
```

As you have mentioned with the current approach I register the sandboxes at two different mediators. One idea to solve this would be the use of a singleton pattern but this conflicts with the architecture and requirejs recommandations..

**So what other ways would I have to let the sandboxes register all to the same instance of Mediator?**

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? If you use the same instance everywhere, then you will have a singleton anyway, no matter how you call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't post comments, I'm going to post an answer.

ggozad explains how to do a singleton in RequireJS here: [Is it a bad practice to use the requireJS module as a singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733201/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-the-requirejs-module-as-a-singleton)

His code:

```
define(function (require) {
    var singleton = function () {
        return {
            ...
        };
    };
    return singleton();
});
```

Comment: There is no reason to have that `singleton` function - just return the object literal

Comment: @ZenMaster: You already do have that with the anonymous function for `define`…

Comment: @Bergi Nope. I meant for scope inside the anonymous function. Default values (starting values) for singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with **RequireJS** you are already receiving singletons, so if you call:

```javascript
require(['mediator'], function(Mediator) {
  ....
});
```

`Mediator` will be always the same object. If it's a constructor function, by calling `new Mediator()` you'll always create a new instance, but you'll **use the same function** each time.

But you don't have to return a function:

```javascript
define([], function() {
    return {
        start: function() {},
        stop: function() {},
        register: function() {},
        unregister: function() {}
    };
});
```

Now your `Mediator` will be an instance, not a function, and you can't use it as function. You're example would now look like:

```javascript
require(['mediator'], function(Mediator) {
  Mediator.register('sandboxOne', SandboxObject);
});
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm using **RequireJS** version build-in in **Dojo**.