# JavaScript: Understanding module based singleton pattern

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, singleton

Thanks to [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753841/1144247) I was able to put something like a singleton pattern into my JavaScript application (single page). Unfortunately I still have problems with understanding how this actually works. This might be related to me not really understanding how a `require()` call actually works in detail.

To quote the linked answer:

> The first require to the module will load and export it. Some other module requiring your singleton will just reuse the already exported one.

(still quoting)

```
define(function (require) {
    var singleton = function () {
        return {
            ...
        };
    };
    return singleton();
});
```

So the process is as follows, just to make sure I understood it. If there is anything wrong, please correct the process description.

In module `A`, I pull in the singleton module.

Inside that module, a function that returns an object is defined. The module's return/export value is the result of that function.

Now in module `B`, I also `require` the singleton module and get back the same object that was created when the singleton was first `require`d.

Where does the singleton data live between the first and the second require?

I just don't get how this object sharing works, I always imagined the `require` as some kind of "virtual pasting", but this seems to be pretty wrong. What is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your code resembles a static instance more than a singleton. If your code lived in a file called 'test' and I did this:

```
var myFunc = require('./test');
```

when the above line runs, myFunc will be the function defined in your code.

However, a true singleton is not initiated until requested like so:

```
define(function(require){ 
  return (function () {

      // Instance stores a reference to the Singleton
      var instance;

      function init() {

        // Singleton

        // Private methods and variables
        function privateMethod(){
            console.log( "I am private" );
        }

        var privateVariable = "Im also private";

        var privateRandomNumber = Math.random();

        return {

          // Public methods and variables
          publicMethod: function () {
            console.log( "The public can see me!" );
          },

          publicProperty: "I am also public",

          getRandomNumber: function() {
            return privateRandomNumber;
          }

        };

      };

      return {

        // Get the Singleton instance if one exists
        // or create one if it doesn't
        getInstance: function () {

          if ( !instance ) {
            instance = init();
          }

          return instance;
        }

      };

    })();
}
```

Check out: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript